# SSO for iOS - Redirect stopped working today

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, redirect, single-sign-on

I have a standard implementation of the Single Sign On for iOS with the AppDelegate listening for the handleOpenURL. Prior to today, this implementation was working fine. I have made no changes to the implementation today, yet the redirect from Facebook in Safari ( on the Simulator ) and the redirect from Facebook app ( on the actual device ) no longer return any data to my app.

I am forwarded to login without issue and login successfully to see that I have already authorized the current app and can now click "Okay", which I do. When the app returns to focus ( after Facebook redirects back to it ), there is no data returned with the redirect.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
     NSLog(@"url recieved: %@", url);
     NSLog(@"query string: %@", [url query]);
     NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);
     NSLog(@"url path: %@", [url path]);

     // from facebook login
     if ( [[url scheme] isEqualToString:FACEBOOK_URL_SCHEME] ) {
          return [SESSION.facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
     }

    return YES;
}
```

The values for all of the logs are empty - the app logs nothing. The request to authorize is below:

```
 NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
      @"publish_actions",
      @"email", 
      @"user_checkins", 
      @"user_likes", 
      @"user_photos", 
      @"offline_access", 
      @"publish_stream",
      @"read_friendlists",
      nil];
 [SESSION.facebook authorize:permissions];
```

Again, this very code worked perfectly yesterday and for the last 3 weeks. Today it simply stopped working. Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if more code is needed to evaluate the issue.

Thanks in advance!
Jane

Answer (score 0):

Now - for no explainable reason it is working again. I *did* check Facebook SDK Status prior to posting here and everything was green. I guess I'll chalk this one up to a blip in the internets.